# Android: blocking and updating listview content in viewpager tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-tablayout

Sorry, but I couldn't find a good solution to my problem. I'm trying to do an app with few tabs (viewpager) Every tab is a different fragment. What I want to do is to click a button in one of tabs/fragments and then update a listview content in another one. Listview itself contains a search result from website. To do a search, I need to pass 2 search parameters as a string. The listview is in Asynctask, I'm using jsoup to parse website content. After start of app, on every try I'm getting error.

My code (imports skipped)

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private Menu menu;
    private NavigationView navView;

    public static String nazwaStanowiska;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        if (navigationView != null) {
            setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
        }

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        if (viewPager != null) {
            setupViewPager(viewPager);
        }

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


        navView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        Menu m = navView.getMenu();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sample_actions, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.add("Cokolwiek");
        item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new SearchFragment(), "Search");
        adapter.addFragment(new ProbaListFragment(), "Results");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        menuItem.setChecked(true);
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

        public Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragments.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitles.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

SearchFragment - this fragment, after buttonClick, should send 2 strings to ProbaListFragment. I know that in frag-activ communication, interfaces are recommended, but first I want to just make all work. And it works as long as I'm passing strings to another fragment, with for example textview.

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {

    private View view;
    static Button mButton;
    private EditText mMiejsce, mStanowisko, mProba;
    public static boolean isButtonClicked = false;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_fragment, container, false);


        mStanowisko = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.stanowisko);
        mMiejsce = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.miejscePracy);

        mProba = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.proba);

        mButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ReceiveFragment.setmyText(mStanowisko.getText().toString());
                //ProbaListFragment.cleanMyJobList();
                ProbaListFragment.setmyText(mStanowisko.getText().toString(), mMiejsce.getText().toString());
                //isButtonClicked = true;
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

and the ProbaListFragment itself:

```
public class ProbaListFragment extends Fragment{

    public Elements jobName, jobName2, jobNameComp, jobName2Comp;

    static List<String> mListaTest1 = new ArrayList<>();
    static List<String> mListaTest2 = new ArrayList<>();
    static List<String> mListaLinki = new ArrayList<>();

    private View view;
    private Button mButton;
    private JazzyListView mListView;
    static ArrayList<String> jobList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private JobListAdapter mAdapter;

    static String tekstPrzekazany;
    static String doURLwork;
    static String doURLplace;


    ViewPager viewPager;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview, container, false);


        viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        mListView = (JazzyListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        mListView.setTransitionEffect(new FanEffect());
        mListView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
        //Progress bar
        //mListView.setEmptyView(view.findViewById(R.id.progressBarLoading));

        new NewThread().execute();

       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wyszukiwanie ofert...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        mAdapter = new JobListAdapter(getContext(), jobList);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Siema", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public static void setmyText(final String stringWork, String stringPlace) {

        doURLwork = stringWork;
        doURLplace = stringPlace;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        super.onResume();
    }

    public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strtext) {

            //String doURLwork = mainActiv.nazwaStanowiska;
            //doURLwork = "kierowca";
            //String doURLplace = mainActiv.nazwaMiejscowosci;
            //doURLplace = "Wroclaw";

            Document doc, doc2, docProba;
            Elements classs, lins, elProba;
            String uerele;
            try {
                doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect("http://www.infopraca.pl/praca?q=" + doURLwork + "&lc=" + doURLplace)
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0").get();
                doc2 = (Document) Jsoup.connect("http://www.pracuj.pl/praca/" + doURLwork + ";kw/" + doURLplace + ";wp")
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0").get();

                docProba = (Document) Jsoup.connect("http://www.infopraca.pl/praca/junior-java-developer/wroclaw/11774542?vj4=1")
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0").get();

                elProba = docProba.select("div#txt-descryption");


                //Elements info = docProba.select("div#txt-description")

                //Oferty
                jobName = doc.select("h2.p-job-title a[href]"); //Infopraca
                jobName2 = doc2.select("h2.offer__list_item_link a[href]");  //pracuj.pl

                //Firmy
                jobNameComp = doc.select("h3.p-name.company a[href]"); //Infopraca
                jobName2Comp = doc2.select("h3.offer__list_item_link a[href]");  //pracuj.pl

                //Oferty pracy
                //Infopraca
                mListaTest1.clear();
                for (Element jobNames : jobName) {
                    mListaTest1.add(jobNames.text() + "\n");
                }

                //Pracuj.pl
                for (Element jobNames2 : jobName2) {
                    mListaTest1.add(jobNames2.text() + "\n");
                }
                if(mListaTest1.size()==0){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Zmie? parametry wyszukiwania!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                //--------------------------------------------------

                //Firmy
                //Infopraca
                mListaTest2.clear();
                for (Element jobNames : jobNameComp) {
                    mListaTest2.add(jobNames.text() + "\n");
                }

                //Pracuj.pl
                for (Element jobNames2 : jobName2Comp) {
                    mListaTest2.add(jobNames2.text() + "\n");
                }

                //Linki do ofert
                //Infopraca
                for (Element link : jobName) {
                    mListaLinki.add(link.attr("abs:href"));
                }

                //Pracuj.pl
                for (Element link : jobName2) {
                    mListaLinki.add(link.attr("abs:href"));
                }

                jobList.clear();
                for(int i=0; i<mListaTest1.size(); i++){
                    jobList.add(mListaTest1.get(i)+"\n"+mListaTest2.get(i));
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix it so it can work in a good way?
Another question is - can i add dynamically a new tab?
I mean - for example - when user clicks button, the tab/fragment with result (listview)appears? OR the tab appears after button click, because now it is visible from the start of app, doesn't matter if the button was already pressed or not.

My logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
            at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
            at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:111)
            at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:324)
            at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:91)
            at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
            at com.support.android.designlibdemo.ProbaListFragment$NewThread.doInBackground(ProbaListFragment.java:174)
            at com.support.android.designlibdemo.ProbaListFragment$NewThread.doInBackground(ProbaListFragment.java:128)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Plz lend me some help guys!

EDIT: Also please tell me why my listview appears only when I click on the EditText in SearchFragment so the keyboard appears, then I go to the ProbaListFragment and press back button (keyboard is hiding then)?

Comment: Please explain your downvotes, so the OP knows what to fix.

Comment: You may want to learn how to read logcat errors. search for the "Caused by" and search it on google. that well give you info about the problem. to find the error line look for the code stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

"Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()." You trying to touch a view to show text in a thread that its not is property.

```
   Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Zmie? parametrywyszukiwania!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

if you want to show toast put it inside runOnUithread or use handler